# Parsing JSON string in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsstring

I have a very very long NSString which has occurrences of {query:"City Name"

The City Name can be of any length. I want to be able to extract all the City Name into an array.

How can I do this?

> {suggestion:[{query:"Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3a5265ea4f7d3361:0x6e61a70b6863d433",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:37},{start:9,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3b00c582b1189633:0x559475cc463361f0",type:545},{start:21,end:26,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"IN",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]}}],target_type:37,confidence:0.54653339144809898},
>
> {query:"Chennai",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0x42a933fdc808d659",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:856338}]},operation:2,target_type:856338,confidence:0.019136800753524912},{query:"Chennai, 1st Avenue, New York, NY, United States",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x89c258ba6002c507:0x73911ed16842e4ba",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:53522},{start:9,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x89c258c29e17b909:0x2bf768350d30b89e",type:17},{start:21,end:29,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62",type:37},{start:31,end:33,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x4ccc4bf0f123a5a9:0xddcfc6c1de189567",type:545},{start:35,end:48,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"US",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",type:33}]}}],target_type:53522,confidence:0.010777814592616199},
>
> {query:"Chennai Insulation, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:18,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3a52675249167ca9:0xaf9a262855cfd248",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:53522},{start:20,end:27,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3a5265ea4f7d3361:0x6e61a70b6863d433",type:37},{start:29,end:39,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3b00c582b1189633:0x559475cc463361f0",type:545},{start:41,end:46,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"IN",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]}}],target_type:53522,confidence:0.0078605968414456173},
>
> {query:"Chennai, Knobelsdorffstraße, Germany",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x47a851282ee06d3b:0xd89e4a3bcf4999a3",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:53522},{start:9,end:27,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x47a850d5ff0b26d9:0xb882dad42f6743db",type:17},{start:29,end:36,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x479a721ec2b1be6b:0x75e85d6b8e91e55b",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"DE",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x479a721ec2b1be6b:0x75e85d6b8e91e55b",type:33}]}}],target_type:53522,confidence:0.0060176870408534602},

Comment: Please provide sample string. Is this in the form of JSon?

Comment: It looks like a corrupted JSon. I have a parser for valid JSon's.

Comment: Use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ for online JSon viewer and try to find the error.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret JSon. I have a parser that is able to parse certain JSon's and not this particular one. It says "Invalid Leading Character".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression that would pluck out that city name is:

```
/query:"([^"]+)"/m
```

That said, the better answer is to get valid JSON from Google (*pretty* sure they can provide that), run it through a JSON parser, and walk the resulting object.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).

This will allow you to access the the contents of the JSON string as a NSArray or NSDictionary object.

Then you code will look something like this:

```
NSString *myJSONStr = ... //Get string
NSArray *myJSONDataObj = [myJSONStr objectFromJSONString];

NSString *cityName = [[myJSONDataObj objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"query"];
```

Comment: still not able to parse. myJSONDataObj initializes to nil.

Comment: It is being returned from google map api and all I want is the city name. Why should I care about the JSon. The solution lies in using NSScanner or NSRegularExpression search to extract city names.

Comment: @crypticcoder - Given the responses you're getting here, you might re-evaluate your certainty about where the solution lies.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically JSON, but invalid syntax, since the property names aren't wrapped in quotes (and also the data's been truncated, but I assume you knew that).  (Also, the "feature_id" values have been garbled, but that doesn't seem to upset the parser.)

Some parsers may accept it anyway, in spite of the problem with the property names, or it would be a fairly simple process to "filter" the quotes into the string.

Comment: the parser I am using is not able to parse it. So I thought of just using Regular Expressions to search the string.

Comment: A regular expression might work once, but is likely to fail the next time, when the data comes back in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete json then add "]}" in the last and then try to parse. I think this should help you.

{suggestion:[{query:"Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3a5265ea4f7d3361:0x6e61a70b6863d433",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:37},{start:9,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3b00c582b1189633:0x559475cc463361f0",type:545},{start:21,end:26,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"IN",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]}}],target_type:37,confidence:0.54653339144809898},

```
{query:"Chennai",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0x42a933fdc808d659",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:856338}]},operation:2,target_type:856338,confidence:0.019136800753524912},{query:"Chennai, 1st Avenue, New York, NY, United States",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x89c258ba6002c507:0x73911ed16842e4ba",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:53522},{start:9,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x89c258c29e17b909:0x2bf768350d30b89e",type:17},{start:21,end:29,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62",type:37},{start:31,end:33,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x4ccc4bf0f123a5a9:0xddcfc6c1de189567",type:545},{start:35,end:48,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"US",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",type:33}]}}],target_type:53522,confidence:0.010777814592616199},

{query:"Chennai Insulation, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:18,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3a52675249167ca9:0xaf9a262855cfd248",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:53522},{start:20,end:27,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3a5265ea4f7d3361:0x6e61a70b6863d433",type:37},{start:29,end:39,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x3b00c582b1189633:0x559475cc463361f0",type:545},{start:41,end:46,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"IN",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6",type:33}]}}],target_type:53522,confidence:0.0078605968414456173},

{query:"Chennai, Knobelsdorffstraße, Germany",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:7,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x47a851282ee06d3b:0xd89e4a3bcf4999a3",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:7,type:53522},{start:9,end:27,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x47a850d5ff0b26d9:0xb882dad42f6743db",type:17},{start:29,end:36,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x479a721ec2b1be6b:0x75e85d6b8e91e55b",type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"DE",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x479a721ec2b1be6b:0x75e85d6b8e91e55b",type:33}]}}],target_type:53522,confidence:0.0060176870408534602},
```

]}

Comment: It's missing quotes around the key names in the objects.